# About Finding Global Maximum and Proving its uniqueness

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

The problem is as shown. I tried using gradient and Hessian but can not make any conclusions from them. Any ideas?

$$\max x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$$

subject to

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1,\quad x_i\geq 0,\quad i=1,2,\ldots,n,$$

where $a_i$ are given positive scalars. Find a global maximum and show that it is unique.

Comment: That looks like an exercise on Lagrange multipliers. And please, post your questions here instead of giving a link.

Comment: @Mark Thanks Mark I am new here and please forgive me for this kind of mistakes. Also, I changed the tag as well.

Comment: Take this as advice: it's a good idea to write in your question what you tried (with technical details) and why it doesn't work for you!

Comment: If it were a continuous function then finding the maximum under the constraint it is an extremum is maybe done via Lagrange multiplier : $g(x)=f(x)-\lambda f'(x)$ then  $x=(f'(x)/f''(x))^{-1}(\lambda)$ then extremize $g(x(\lambda))$ and find lambda as usual. I don't know if this method can be applied to your case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling $f = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{\alpha_k}$ we have the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,\mu) = f - \mu\left(\sum_{k=1}^n x_k-1\right)
$$

then the stationary points are determined by

$$
\alpha_k \frac{f}{x_k}-\mu = 0,\ \ \ k = 1,\cdots, n\\
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k-1=0
$$

or making $\lambda = \frac{\mu}{f}$

$$
\frac{\alpha_k}{x_k}-\lambda = 0\\
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k-1=0
$$

$\lambda$'s value is obtained substituting $x_k = \frac{\alpha_k}{\lambda}$ so

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k-\lambda=0
$$

and also $x_k = \frac{\alpha_k}{\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k}$

etc.

Comment: Yeah I came up with the same answer as yours, took me so long. Thank you so much. For the uniqueness, do you compute the Hessian of the function?

Comment: @RickyShao Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix concerning bordered hessians.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a homework, so I'll give you a hint instead of a complete solution. To maximize your function is the same as to maximize
$$
F(x)=\ln(x_1^{a_1}x_2^{a_2}\ldots x_n^{a_n})=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\ln x_i.
$$
The condition $x_i\ge 0$ cannot be active at the maximum, hence, we do not need it in the Lagrange equation for the gradients. Use Lagrange multipliers to conclude the necessary condition as
$$
\frac{a_i}{x_i}+v=0.
$$
Express each $x_i$, use the equality condition to find $v$, and finally find $x_i$.

The new problem is concave, then the Lagrange condition is also sufficient. The objective function $F$ is strictly concave, hence, the maximum is unique.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your answer, I used the same method as @Cesareo to solve the first part of the problem. Your solution provides an easy way to prove the uniqueness of the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @RickyShao You are welcome.